# How to make a test that executes all Boost unit tests

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, boost

Say I have several files with Boost unit tests: test1.cc, test2.cc...
...

Each with a:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE (test1)
    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_something)
    ...
    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_something_else)
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END ()
```

My CMake then creates an executable for each of the cc files and I can execute the resulting binary for the tests.

Is there a way to create another file called execute_all_tests.cc, which does an include of all the other test*.cc and calls them, so that the binary of this program can execute all of them at once?

I have seen this: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/runtime-config/run-by-name.html

But it's for terminal. What I want is an executable that calls all the tests.

Thanks for your help

Comment: For what do you want that? You can easily execute all with the wildcard `*`?

Comment: For me it looks like a problem with a build definition (`cmake`) not problem with `Boost.Test`. Please provide respective details.

Comment: How? With a bash script? I was hoping I could just have an executable that internally called them. I want to be able to execute all the tests for a gitlab continuous integration pipeline, and wanted to know if it was possible this way instead of calling each executable

Answer (score 2):

Within your CMakeLists.txt you can define an executable which links all test case object files, instead of creating one executable per test case file.

Your CMakeLists.txt will contain something like the following

```
    enable_testing()
    add_executable(execute_all_tests execute_all_tests.cc test1.cc test2.cc)
    add_test(NAME allMyTests COMMAND execute_all_tests)
```

Your execute_all_tests.cc can contain the following code (using the single-header variant, as explained here : https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/usage-variants/single-header-variant.html)

```cpp
    #define BOOST_TEST_MODULE AllTests
    #include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
```

Call to execute_all_tests binary specified in CMakeLists.txt can use command line arguments to tune its execution.